# Is it possible to add some procedures and functions to a custom SQL Server docker file?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have this `Dockerfile` to customize a SQL Server image for our developers:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/Company/Commands/DatabaseContainer"
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=************
ENV MSSQL_PID=Express
USER root
```

And it works well. However, we have some functions and procedures that we add to `master` and `model` databases and right now our developers need to run them manually.

I wonder, if it's possible for me to add them during the creation of this docker image?

Is that possible and if so, how?

P.S. I already know about [entrypoint](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app), but it is not embedded into the image.

Comment: Can't you install `sqlcmd` temporarily, `COPY` the SQL files with the definitions, and `RUN sqlcmd -i file1.sql,file2.sql`?

Comment: @dezso, the point is, `sqlserver` process is not started yet. That can not be done I guess. Maybe I can start the process, and wait for it to load, and run scripts. I have to test it.

Comment: You mentioned `main` and `model` databases. Do you mean `master` and `model`?

Comment: @DanGuzman, yes, my bad. I meant master.